# Problems with vertical position of text centered between 2 floating images

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I run this code, the text "Text Here" moves to the bottom of the div, when I want it at the top. There isn't anything in the .subText styling at the moment but i have tried vertical-align, padding and margin-top but can't seem to figure it out.

HTML and CSS:

```css
#footballLeft {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#footballRight {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.subText {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sect sectTwo"></div>
<div id="footballSection" class="subSection">
  <h1 class="titles">FOOTBALL</h1>
  <div class="subSubSection">
    <img src="img/teamhuddle.jpg" height="30%" width="30%" alt="Team Huddle" id="footballLeft" />
    <img src="img/womens1.jpg" alt="Womens First Team" height="30%" width="30%" id="footballRight" />
    <p class="subText">Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser? https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/84mywkvj/ show the text is on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine, but I found that I had another section in my CSS which I had turned into a comment while experimenting and forgot to include the closing bracket in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works fine to me . you can try it again by restarting your browser or try by adding this piece of code

```
.subText {

 position:relative;
 left: 220px;
  }
```

which work same as center does.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is already showing at the top for me.
Note: Floated elements are not affected by vertical-align

Is using display:inline-block possible instead of using floats?
https://jsfiddle.net/xw9fce28/

Html:

```
<div class="sect sectTwo"></div>
    <div id="footballSection" class="subSection">
    <h1 class="titles">FOOTBALL</h1>
    <div class="subSubSection">
    <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg" height="30%" width="30%" alt="Team Huddle" class="football" />  
    <p class="subText">Text Here</p> 
    <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg" alt="Womens First Team" height="30%" width="30%" class="football" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.football {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
.subText {
    display:inline-block;
}
```